# search&replace on huge txt files

Tags: text-files, text-processing

I need a text processing tool that can perform search and replace operations PER LINE on HUGE TEXT FILES (>0.5 GB). Can be either windows or linux based. (I don't know if there is anything like a streamreader/writer in Linux but I have a feeling that it would be the ideal solution. The editors I have tries so far load the whole file into the momory.)

Bonus question: a tool that can MERGE two huge texts on a per line basis, separated with e.g. tabs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you want sed. For example,

```
sed 's/foo/bar/' < big-input-file > big-output-file
```

should replace the first occurrence of `foo` by `bar` in each line of `big-input-file`, writing the results to `big-output-file`.

**Bonus answer:** I just learned about [paste](http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/paste-invocation.html), which seems to be exactly what you want for your bonus question.

Answer (score 1):

'sed' is built into Linux/Unix, and is available for Windows. I believe that it only loads a buffer at a time (not the whole file) -- you might try that.

What would you be trying to do with the merge -- interleaved in some way, rather than just concatenating?

Add: interleave.pl

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $B;

open INA, $ARGV[0];
open INB, $ARGV[1];

while (<INA>) {
  print $_;
  $B = <INB>;
  print $B;
}

close INA;
close INB;
```

run: perl interleave.pl fileA fileB > mergedFile

Note that this is a very bare-bones utility. It does not check if the files exist, and it expects that the files have the same number of lines.

Comment: I want to make a bilingual (parallel) corpus out of two monolingual corpora.

Comment: So it would be "one line from A, one from B, one from A, one from B,..."? I don't think there's anything built-in to do that, but as mentioned below, something like Perl could do that in just a few lines. If that's what you want, we could give you the Perl code to do it. You would just have to make sure Perl is installed.

Comment: A very simple merge utility (interleaved lines) provided as an edit to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I would use perl for this. It is easy to read a file line by line, has great search/repace available using regular expressions, and will enable you to merge, and you can make your perl script aware of both files.

Comment: It's the first language I learnt and it's my answer for everything ;)

Comment: I have a weather forecasting model I need written. You do it in Perl and I'll do it in FORTRAN, and we'll compare performance :) Perl can do a lot of things nicely, but it's not the best for everything.